# React double map and filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have data coming from an API that provides an object with a year. I'm creating headings with possible years, and then I'd like to display the data of the object if it matches that year. There can be multiple objects that match the same year.

What I'm doing currently, but with no avail:

Simplified example:

```
export default function App() {
  const years = [2020, 2019, 2018];
  const data = [{ year: 2019, test: "test" }];

  return (
    <div>
      {years.map((year) => (
        <h1>{year}</h1>
        {data.map(d => (
          <div>{d}</div>
        ))}
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

This doesnt display anything. What could I be missing? Should I filter instead of check for a condition? The code doesn't seem to loop inside a loop (map inside a map). Should I be able to do this, considering the syntax, as this returns:

> Unexpected token, expected "," (11:8)

Comment: Please update your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the problem, ideally a runnable one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support).

Comment: Seems you don't return anything from data.map function. Remove `{` or add `return` before your condition and try again

Comment: Edited to be a bit better example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

{years.map(year => {
return div key="key" h1 {year} h1 {data.filter(el=>el.year === year).map(el2 => h2 {el2} h2)} div}

Comment: Had to decrypt a bit, but this solution worked, ty!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<div>
  {years.map((year) => <>
    <h1>{year}</h1>
    {data.map(d => (
      <div>{d.year}</div>
    ))}
  </>)}
</div>
```

If you want to also have a condition inside your map function, use this:

```
<div>
  {years.map((year) => <>
    <h1>{year}</h1>
    {data.map(d => (
      d.year === year &&
      <div>{d.year}</div>
    ))}
  </>)}
</div>
```

Comment: Well that looks nicer than mine!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow @ColdDarkness :D , write your code in a pair of backticks if you want it to be inline like `this`. If you want to write multi lines of code like the way I wrote in my answer, you need to use "code fences" which consist of three backticks before and after your code block. Read this to learn more: [official doc](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: Oh thanks, forgot about them! But when I was saying "nicer" I was talking about my .filter and your && solution that doesnt iterate twice.